# AJAX Live Search Not Showing Results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Have a live search page as shown in livesearch.php below, when typing entries into the input box am not getting any results show under it. The html code and script in search.php are shown beelow.

**search.php**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
       <header>
            <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       </header>
       <body>
            <div id="searchContainer">
                <div class="searchMainTitle">Search Schedules</div>
                    <div class="searchSubTitle">
                <p>Enter any information you wish, this will search all schedule fields.</p>
                </div>
            <form role="form" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" size="100%" placeholder="Enter Search Term(s) Here" id="keyword" />
            </form>
                    <ul id="liveSearch"></ul>       

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
            var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
            if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {
        $.post('livesearch.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                    $('ul#liveSearch').empty()
                    $.each(data, function() {
                    $('ul#liveSearch').append('<li><a href="schedPopup.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>');  
                    });
                }, "json"); 
            }
        });
    }); 
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The livesearch.php that is being referenced by the script is shown below

**livesearch.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'dbconnect.php';

echo "Keyword: ".$_POST['keywords']."<br/><br/>";
    $liveSearchArray = array();
        if (!empty($_POST['keywords'])) {
            $keywords = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
            $sql = "SELECT OWNER_SURNAME,OWNER_FIRSTNAMES,OWNER_TITLE FROM testucm_owners WHERE OWNER_SURNAME LIKE '%".$keywords."%'";
            $result = $connection->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "We Have A Result, There Are ".$result->num_rows." Rows";
                while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
                    $liveSearchArray[] = array('id' => $obj->OWNER_SURNAME, 'title' => $obj->OWNER_TITLE);
                }
            } else {
                echo "No Matches";
            }
        }

 echo json_encode($liveSearchArray);

 mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

If a manually add a value for keywords into the livesearch.php query I get the correct results, however no resutls display if I enter search terms via search.php. I have partially test this by putting an alert after `var searchKeyword = $(this).val();`, this shows the correct term as typed in however still no results showing.

I suspect the error may be with this line of code:

```
$('ul#liveSearch').append('<li><a href="schedPopup.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>');
```

Either that or for some reason the $liveSearchArray is not being passed back to the script, however I'm unable to determine where the error lies or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check the php return data.
here:

```
 echo "We Have A Result, There Are ".$result->num_rows." Rows";
```

see,the return data is not pure json.
I think that may be the key.

When you expect data for "json", you have to keep the return data is only json ,not anything else.Otherwise ,the ajax will get an  parse error which is not displayed directly,and your "success" function will not be executed.And **it seems like you don't get the data**,but actually it's because you get the wrong format data.

It works like this:[image: ajax test]

Comment: @aboutx - just running the livesearch.php gives the result as 3 rows. the echo json_encode gives results of:  [{"id":"Wilkins","title":"Mr"},{"id":"Wilson","title":"Miss"},{"id":"Wilkins","title":"Mrs"}]  ... which are correct.

Comment: add this `.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(textStatus+':'+ errorThrown)})` to your ajax.There may help.

Comment: Have tried it with both and one or the other echos commented out, but still no result. Tried adding that code after `}, "json");` but the console gave an error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','`

Comment: like this:`$.post('livesearch.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                    $('ul#liveSearch').empty()
                    $.each(data, function() {
                    $('ul#liveSearch').append('<li><a href="schedPopup.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>');  
                    });
                }, "json").fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(textStatus+':'+ errorThrown)})` . That will show what's wrong,check your firebug console.

Comment: As your return data is not json,you will see the error on console,`parsererror:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` . And the "success" function  of course will not be executed. You can have a "console.log" to check if the function is executed.

Comment: Okay, ran that, got an error in the console `parsererror:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` so that gives me something to start looking for thanks :)

Comment: The output from the array is shown in my first comment above, however I can't figure out what is actually causing the error.

Comment: OK, have removed all of my added echo's etc so the only output is the `echo json_encode`. Not getting any error now however still no results. Checked the console the POST keywords wil, with source keywords=wil (which is what I type in) but the Response is blank, just gives [] :(

Comment: I'm guessing this means that for some reason $liveSearchArray results aren't being passed back to the AJAX properly and populating the `$.each(data, function() { $('ul#liveSearchList').append('<li><a href="schedpopup.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.title + '</a></li>');  });`, what I can't answer is why??

Comment: Well,have some var_dump in your php and see what's wrong

Comment: As you said the Response is blank , i think that means the php can't return the right data.

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying, the var_dump results for keyword 'Wil' are as follows: `array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(7) "Wilkins" ["title"]=> string(2) "Mr" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "Wilson" ["title"]=> string(4) "Miss" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(7) "Wilkins" ["title"]=> string(3) "Mrs" } } `

Comment: That results are right,but why your Response is []?You mean your  return data of $.post is []?

Comment: I had  a test,the html page is working right with static json.If your ajax get the right data,that will works well.[the link](http://aboutqx.github.io/test/xxx.htm).As post is forbidden in github,change to get.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't take this to chat so will have to comment here. I just tried it again and looking in the Firebug console the Post Parameters: `keywords wil`. Now when I look under Response it gives me the same output as the var_dump above so it seems it's not been sent back to the html page. I'm sorry I don't understand the last part of your comment above.

Comment: add console.log like : `$.each(data, function() {
        console.log(this);
                    $('ul#liveSearch').append('<li><a href="schedPopup.php?id=' + this.id + '">' + this.title+ '</a></li>');  
                    });` to see what your ajax get.

Comment: My last comment have a test in github with Get request as Post request is not allowed there.And with the test you can see the js codes are right.But i'm curious why your ajax get empty data.Could i have the link of your page?

Comment: Console response output: `Keyword: wil<br/><br/>[{"id":"Wilkins","title":"Mr"},{"id":"Wilson","title":"Miss"},{"id":"Wilkins","title":"Mrs"}] `, error `parsererror:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: Sorry, it's just internal WAMPP on my PC.

Comment: Well, you should have deleted other output and make the respone like:[{"id":"Wilkins","title":"Mr"},{"id":"Wilson","title":"Miss"},{"id"‌​:"Wilkins","title":"Mrs"}].Only with right json format,your `success` will work

Comment: with the json_encode and var_dump echo'd out in livesearch.php get response output: `Keyword: wil<br/><br/>`  with the same error message as above

Comment: Just delete var_dump,that's for debug to see if your data from database is right.You have to make sure your Respone is json format like my picture shows.You may forget to delete `echo "Keyword: ".$_POST['keywords']."<br/><br/>";`

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten to delete the echo Keyword, now the response field is just blank and has the same error message.

Comment: Oh my, I just re-enabled the `echo json_encode` and it looks like it's actually working!!!